# Prevent rendering of Layout Builder regions that have no content

Tags: 8, theming, layout-builder

Using Layout Builder, when you add a block to a layout that has access controls and a user visits a page without access, the layout is empty.

How does one prevent the layout from rendering at all if its contents are empty? While the `{% if content.foo|render|striptags|trim %}` trick works for block templates, I can't figure out how to get the same effect with layout templates.

The end result is I have extra markup in the page, which is classed and creating extra padding and vertical space between populated layout regions.

edit:

I have updated now with an event that Layout Builder needs:

```
class MyModuleEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  /**
   * Layout Builder response event handler.
   *
   * @param SectionComponentBuildRenderArrayEvent $event
   *   Build render event.
   */
  public function onBuildRender(SectionComponentBuildRenderArrayEvent $event) {
    $id = $event->getPlugin()->getPluginDefinition()['id'];

    if ($id == 'inline_block' && !$event->inPreview()) {
      $build = $event->getBuild();
      $build['#create_placeholder'] = FALSE;
      $event->setBuild($build);
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() : array {
    $events[LayoutBuilderEvents::SECTION_COMPONENT_BUILD_RENDER_ARRAY] = ['onBuildRender', 110];
    return $events;
  }

}
```

[image: xdebug]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by placeholdering. Drupal formats placeholders as HTML tag. In your render test, `striptags` removes such placeholders, even if later, when the real rendering is happening, it is filled with a lazily-built block.

You can avoid it, at the expense of cache performance, by denying the block being placeholdered:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_build_BASE_BLOCK_ID_alter().
 */
function mymodule_block_build_example_block_alter(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface $block) {
  // Disable placeholdering of this block.
  $build['#create_placeholder'] = FALSE;
}
```

See [Can BigPipe exclude certain blocks?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/305479/can-bigpipe-exclude-certain-blocks) This is not depending on BigPipe being enabled or not, but I think for both problems the solution is the same.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129156/discussion-on-answer-by-4k4-prevent-rendering-of-layout-builder-regions-that-hav).