# How do I prevent a block from being loaded via Big Pipe

Tags: views, blocks, ajax, 9

I have a view block, nothing crazy, just a couple fields. I want to present it as a carousel. Everything worked fine, until suddenly Drupal decided to start loading the block asynchronously with Big Pipe. Since I have js library attached to the block, all DOMContentLoaded functions in that js stopped working. How can I prevent it? I need the carousel to work across multiple blocks and I need a reliable solution for blocks that are both loaded with Big Pipe and blocks that aren't as well. Preferably I would like to be able to disable Big Pipe aggregation for specific blocks.

Comment: You could attach js in Drupal Behaviors so that it works with AJAX. Otherwise this is a duplicate of this question https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/305479/can-bigpipe-exclude-certain-blocks.