# Wrong user with currentUser() on prod

Tags: users, caching, 9

I'm getting the name of my user that I load from the profile. It's works fine on my local, but on my prod, the firstname displayed is showing the name from the previous user. How do I prevent that ? This is how I get my data.

This is where I don't understand, I'm loading data by current user, but the user isn't the good one...

I have my "new" firstname only after clearing my website cache with drush

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function frr_menu_link_preprocess_menu__account(&$variables)
{
    $current_user = \Drupal::currentUser();
    $variables['firstname'] = FALSE;
    if($current_user->isAuthenticated()) {
        $entity_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
        $profileStorage = $entity_manager->getStorage('profile');
        $profileCustomerFound = $profileStorage->loadByProperties([
            'uid' => $current_user->id(),
            'type' => 'customer',
            'is_default' => 1,
            'status' => 1,
        ]);
        if($profileCustomerFound > 0) {
            $customer = end($profileCustomerFound);
            $firstname = $customer->get('field_firstname')->value;
            $variables['firstname'] = !empty($firstname) ? ucfirst($firstname) : FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "previous" user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely because you must add [cacheability metadata](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/cache-api) so Drupal knows to cache the content separately by user.

Comment: Obligatory mention - varying cache per user is not a great idea as the number of cache entries can get large. Lazy builders and placeholders can be used in this sort of scenario. There's a good post with examples here: https://www.qed42.com/insights/coe/drupal/lazy-builders-drupal-8-caching-ftw, and if you search this site for [lazy_builder](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=lazy_builder) there are plenty of other examples and explanations

Comment: My website has about 160000 user for now, with the "dev" amount of users I have no problem... So can I add cacheability metadata ?

Comment: If so, how do I do this ?

Comment: If you have this amount of users then add `$variables['#cache'] = ['max-age' => 0];` to prevent the menu to be cached for every user visiting the page. In this case a lazy builder is not absolutely necessary because menus are usually rendered in blocks and blocks have already a lazy builder.

Comment: Although a separate lazy builder only for $variables['firstname'] would be nice. This makes the page load more fluid when the dynamic parts are restricted to the absolute minimum. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/305479/can-bigpipe-exclude-certain-blocks

Comment: `$variables['#cache'] = ['max-age' => 0];` worked fine, thanks !